# I want to get table record using linq query but start from other row not from first row

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, linq

I have table in SQL

```
id   datetime     
---|------------|
1  | January    |
2  | February   | 
3  | March      | 
4  | April      |
5  | May        |  
6  | June       | 
7  | July       | 
8  | August     | 
9  | September  | 
10 | October    | 
11 | November   | 
12 | December   |
```

When select record result start from january but I want to get complete record but start from july...

Comment: could you please provide your expected output in table format?

Comment: [Queryable.Skip(IQueryable<TSource>, Int32) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.skip?view=netframework-4.7.2)  and [Queryable.OrderBy Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.orderby?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: id   datetime     
---|------------|
7  | July|
8  | August   | 
9  | September      | 
10  | October     |
11 | November       |  
12  | December       | 
1  | January       | 
2  | Feb     | 
3  | March  | 
4 | April    | 
5 | May   | 
6 | June   |

Comment: You need something like `Union` or `Concat` I think the accepted answer here is what you are looking for : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11426615/linq-union-usage However, if the set of records is small, I would take the whole set and rearrange it on the application server.

Comment: @NaveedAhmad, please show some code that you did.

Comment: am just getting list of record.. Like that..   var Monthslist = Model.Select(d => d.MonthId).Distinct().ToList();

Comment: @NaveedAhmad, try this => `var Monthslist = Model.Where(d => d.MonthId > 6).Select(d => d.MonthId).Distinct().ToList();` and let me know

Comment: @er-shoaib I have try this but getting same record..

Comment: @NaveedAhmad, please show your code that show how you'd implement above code?

Comment: var Monthslist = Model.Where(d => d.MonthId > 6).Select(d => d.MonthId).Distinct().ToList();
                                                   foreach (var item in Monthslist)
                                                   {
                                                       
                                                       var months = Model.Where(d => d.MonthId == item).FirstOrDefault();

Comment: Please EDIT YOUR QUESTION with what you have tried, don't post it in the comments.

Comment: @NaveedAhmad, what you try to do in `foreach` ? bcoz you already have `item` with `MonthId`  you do not need to do so...

Answer (score 0):

You want to start from July so first make list which start from july. And then union it with rest of items.

Try with this

```
var result = modelList.Where(x => x.id > 6).ToList().
                Union(modelList.Where(y => y.id < 7).Distinct().ToList()).ToList();
```