# How to select from multiple tables using LINQ using a union query to return only one column?

Tags: linq, model-view-controller, union

I have two tables. I would like to perform a union query uning LINQ to select from two tables but only return one column.

**Table 1:**

```
ID, Name1, Email
```

**Table 2:**

```
ID, Name2, Email
```

Select Name1 and Name2 from the tables to return one column.

So, I'd like to select

```
Name
--------
Helen 
Mike 
Joe
```

Not :

```
Name1
-------
Helen
Mike 

Name2
-------
Joe
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried and tell us what issue you had.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linq union usage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11426615/linq-union-usage)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to select only the Names you could,

```
var result = table1.Select(x=>x.Name1).Union(table2.Select(x=>x.Name2));
```

For example, emulating your scenario using collection.

```
var table1 = new List<Table1>
{
    new Table1{ID=1,Name1="Helen ",Email=""},
    new Table1{ID=2,Name1="Mike",Email=""},
};

var table2 = new List<Table2>
{
    new Table2{ID=1,Name2="Joe",Email=""},
};
```

Where

```
public class Table1
{
public int ID {get;set;}
public string Name1{get;set;}
public string Email{get;set;}
}

public class Table2
{
public int ID {get;set;}
public string Name2{get;set;}
public string Email{get;set;}
}
```

The Query would return

```
Helen  
Mike 
Joe
```

Please be aware that Union would be eliminating the duplicates. If you would like to include duplicates, Concat would be the way to go. If you are interested to read more on the difference, [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13417556/union-vs-concat-in-linq) would be a good reference

Comment: You may want to mention the difference between `Concat` and `Union`.

Comment: Glad to help you.