# Join and sort 2 not related tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have 2 entities: Post and Article and I need to select both of them at once and sort by common property. I'm searching for some "join" possibilities, but all I'm finding are examples ending with something like `...where a.id == b.a_id` which is not relevant in my case.

That's my models

```
class BaseEntity {
    public int Id;
    public DateTime AddedDate;
}

class Post extends BaseEntity {
    public string Title;
}

class Article extends BaseEntity {
    public string Name;
}
```

For that data:

```
Articles:
Id | Name | AddedDate
 1 | AAA  | 15/05/2020 18:00:00
 2 | BBB  | 17/05/2020 18:00:00
 3 | CCC  | 19/05/2020 18:00:00

Posts:
Id | Title | AddedDate
 1 | DDD   | 16/05/2020 18:00:00
 2 | EEE   | 18/05/2020 18:00:00
 3 | FFF   | 20/05/2020 18:00:00
```

when sorting by date DESC and limit it to 4 i need to end up with something like that, or something similar:

```
Article Id | PostId | Name  | Title | AddedDate
NULL       | 3      | NULL  | FFF   | 20/05/2020 18:00:00
3          | NULL   | CCC   | NULL  | 19/05/2020 18:00:00
NULL       | 2      | NULL  | EEE   | 18/05/2020 18:00:00
2          | NULL   | BBB   | NULL  | 17/05/2020 18:00:00
```

Could someone advice me somehow? I need to do this in EF Core.

I could construct whole list similarly to this and manipulate on this, but this is very far from being optimal:

```
var results = (new List<BaseEntity>()).Concat(_context.Posts.ToList());
results = results.Concat(_context.Articles.ToList()).ToList();

//order
//take(x)
```

Comment: For this example please check the top answer from the stack link [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11426615/linq-union-usage][1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve the result you need you will have to project both `Post` and `Article` to a shared typed, so first I created a `ResultDto` - which is representation of the type that you want to get:

```
public class ResultDto
{
    public int? ArticleId { get; set; }
    public int? PostId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime AddedDate { get; set; }
}
```

Then you have to project `Articles` to `ResultDto`, as well as `Post` to `ResultDto`, concat the results and sort like this:

```
var result = _dbContext
            .Articles.Select(a => new ResultDto()
            {
                ArticleId = a.Id,
                AddedDate = a.AddedDate,
                Name = a.Name,
                PostId = null,
                Title = null
            }).Concat(_dbContext.Posts.Select(p => new ResultDto()
            {
                PostId = p.Id,
                AddedDate = p.AddedDate,
                Title = p.Title,
                ArticleId = null,
                Name = null
            }))
            .OrderByDescending(r => r.AddedDate)
            .ToList();
```

Btw since this `Select` is invoked on an `IQueryable`, you will have to select all of the properties (even if they would be NULL by default).

This results in following SQL query:

```
SELECT [t].[ArticleId], [t].[AddedDate], [t].[Name], [t].[PostId], [t].[Title]
FROM (
          SELECT [a].[Id] AS [ArticleId], [a].[AddedDate], [a].[Name], NULL AS [PostId], NULL AS [Title]
          FROM [Articles] AS [a]
          UNION ALL
          SELECT NULL AS [ArticleId], [p].[AddedDate], NULL AS [Name], [p].[Id] AS [PostId], [p].[Title]
          FROM [Posts] AS [p]
      ) AS [t]
ORDER BY [t].[AddedDate] DESC
```

Comment: Thanks. It works as i wanted after `AsEnumerable()` added before `Concat` according to this: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/18091#issuecomment-536069419. I'm using EF Core 3.1.4.